# Configuring SSL in dropwizard using code

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jetty, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard **0.7.0-rc2** for REST API. I have tried configuring SSL through config.yaml and it is working on local machine.

Below is the content in **config.yaml**

```
server:
#  softNofileLimit: 1000
#  hardNofileLimit: 1000
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
    - type: https
      port: 13790
      keyStorePath: xxx.keystore
      keyStorePassword: xxx
      validateCerts: false
      validatePeers: false
    #this requires the alpn-boot library on the JVM's boot classpath
    #- type: h2
    #  port: 8445
    #  keyStorePath: xxx.keystore
    #  keyStorePassword: xxx
    #  validateCerts: false
    #  validatePeers: false
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
    - type: https
      port: 13790
      keyStorePath: xxxx.keystore
      keyStorePassword: xxxxx
      validateCerts: false
      validatePeers: false
```

I  tried with this on production server but it gives me the error *Failed to parse configuration at: server.applicationConnectors; Could not resolve type id 'http' into a subtype*

Then I tried by adding code.

```
public void run(MyConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
            throws Exception {

        ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getApplicationConnectors().add(new HttpsConnectorFactory());
        ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getAdminConnectors().add(new HttpsConnectorFactory());
        ((HttpConnectorFactory) ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getApplicationConnectors().get(0)).setPort(13789);
        ((HttpConnectorFactory) ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getAdminConnectors().get(0)).setPort(13777);

        ((HttpsConnectorFactory) ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getApplicationConnectors().get(1)).setPort(13790);
        ((HttpsConnectorFactory) ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getAdminConnectors().get(1)).setPort(13791);



        HttpsConnectorFactory cf1 = (HttpsConnectorFactory) ((HttpConnectorFactory) ((DefaultServerFactory)  configuration.getServerFactory()).getApplicationConnectors().get(1));
        cf1.setKeyStoreType("JKS");
        cf1.setKeyStorePath("/var/***.jks");
        cf1.setKeyStorePassword("*****");
        cf1.setValidateCerts(true);
        cf1.setValidatePeers(true);

        }
```

By above code,it binds the port but fail to connect.

I get following error while testing using **openssl**

```
140573632874312:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1457936036
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I have also tried with using shaded-jar for deployment, but it was not working.

Please help me resolve the issue.